# How do I extract the content of quoted strings from the output of a command?

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have output from `VBoxManage list vms` which looks like this:

```
"arch" {de1a1db2-86c5-43e7-a8de-a0031835f7a7}   
"arch2" {92d8513c-f13e-41b5-97e2-2a6b17d47b67}
```

I need to grab the names `arch` and `arch2` and save them into a variable.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

#### Using grep + sed

This will parse the contents of those 2 strings:

```
$ grep -o '".*"' somefile | sed 's/"//g'
arch
arch2
```

The above looks for a string matching the pattern `".*"`. That will match anything that occurs within double quotes. So `grep` will return these types of values:

```
"arch"
"arch2"
```

The pipe to `sed` will strip off any double quotes from these strings giving your the strings you're looking for. The notation `sed 's/"//g'` is instructing `sed` to do a search and replace on all occurrences of double quotes, substituting them with nothing, `s/"//g`. The command `s/find/replace/g` is what's going on there, and the trailing `g` to search tells it to do it globally on the entire string that it's given.

#### Using just sed

You can also use `sed` to chop off the beginning double quote, keep what's in between them, and chop off the remaining quote + everything there after:

```
$ sed 's/^"\(.*\)".*/\1/' a
arch
arch2
```

#### Other methods

```
$ grep -o '".*"' somefile | tr -d '"'
arch
arch2
```

The command `tr` can be used to delete characters. In this case it's deleting the double quotes.

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=").*(?=")' somefile
arch
arch2
```

Using `grep`'s PCRE feature you can look for any substrings that begin with a double quote or end with a double quote and report just the substring.

Comment: Very nice! It works. I would also appreciate a little explanation please.

Comment: `tr -d \"` is another way to delete the quotes. (`tr`normally translates one set of characters into another; `-d` tells it to just delete them instead.)

Comment: @deltab, yes, in `grep -o | sed`, slm is using a non-standard extension of `grep` to do `sed`'s job and `sed` to do `tr`'s job.

Comment: @deltab - thanks, added that as an A. Gave the OP a quick way to do this. Nothing more.

Comment: slm - if you add an `/address/` to `sed` like `sed '/^"\(arch[^"]*\)/s//\1/` you'll only operate on lines containing that string.

Comment: @mikeserv - true, wasn't sure how consistent the arch was going to be in his output. But if it is, then that would work too.

Comment: good point slm. There's no indication that will be consistent. Sorry.

Comment: I just realized though that your `sed` really should be doing `s/^"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/` just in case there are than only two double-quotes on the line.

Comment: @mikeserv - yeah I thought of the double quotes but the output that this command will return won't ever have them so I omitted that requirement. The cmd `VBoxManage  list vms` only shows exactly the format of output that the OP's showing above. If you have more virtual machines then you'll have a longer list, but the formatting of the output will be more of the same.

Answer (score 33):

That's another job for `cut`:

```
VBoxManage list vms | cut -d \" -f2
```

Comment: Very neat! How it works: `cut` splits each line into fields using the quote mark as delimiter, then outputs field 2: field 1 is the empty string before the first quote, field 2 is the wanted string between the quotes, and field 3 is the rest of the line.

Answer (score 8):

With `sed` you can do:

```
var=$(VBoxManage list vms | sed 's/^"\([^"]*\).*/\1/')
```

Explanation:

- `s/.../.../` - match and replace
- `^`- match at start of line
- `\(...\)` - this is a back reference, we can refer to what is matched in here later with `\1`
- `[^"]*` - match any sequence that does not contain a `"` (ie up to the the next `"`)
- `.*` - match the rest of the line
- `\1` - replace with the back reference

Or with `awk`:

```
var=$(VBoxManage list vms | awk -F\" '{ print $2 }')
```

Note that in modern shells you can also use an array instead of a normal variable. In `bash` you can do:

```
IFS=$'\n'; set -f
array=( $(VBoxManage list vms | awk -F\" '{ print $2 }') )
echo "array[0] = ${array[0]}"
echo "array[1] = ${array[1]}"
```

This might be easier when you come to use the variable.

Comment: Would you break that sed command up for me please?

Answer (score 6):

And the one through grep oneliner with `--perl-regexp` option,

```
VBoxManage list vms | grep -oP '(?<=^\")[^"]*'
```

**Explanation:**

`(?<=^\")[^"]*` -> A lookbehind is used here. It matches any character but not of `"` zero or more times(once it find a double quotes, it stops matching) which are just after double quotes(only the line that starts with double quotes).

Another Ugly hack through `sed`,

```
$ sed '/.*\"\(.*\)\".*/ s//\1/g' file
arch
arch2
```

Answer (score 5):

Using bash, I'd write:

```
while read vm value; do
    case $vm in
        '"arch"') arch=$value ;;
        '"arch2"') arch2=$value ;;
    esac
done < <( VBoxManage list vms )
echo $arch
echo $arch2
```

Answer (score 3):

since regex has greedy and non-greedy modes, if you have multiple targets on the same line, it would not extract as you wish.
Line:

```
"tom" is a cat, and "jerry" is a mouse.
```

Target:

```
tom
jerry
```

Command (greedy mode):

```
grep -oP '".*"' name
```

Command (non-greedy mode):

```
grep -oP '".*?"' name
```

Comment: Add `| tr -d '"'` at the end to remove the quotes.

Comment: `echo "\"tom\" is a cat, and \"jerry\" is a mouse." | tee >(cut -d \" -f 2) >(cut -d \" -f 4) >/dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

Here, we are using [capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1892107/1772898):

```
$ grep -oP '"\K.*(?=")' somefile 
arch
arch2
```

If you want to use ripgrep, then the syntax looks like:

```
$ rg '"(.*)"' somefile -r '$1' 
arch
arch2
```

In addition to [Tiina's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553516/206574), if you have multiple targets on the same line

In [Tiina's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553516/206574) context,If you want to use ripgrep then:

```
echo "\"tom\" is a cat, and \"jerry\" is a mouse." | rg '"(.*?)"' --only-matching --replace '$1'
```

If you do not have rigprep (In [Tiina's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553516/206574) context), then:

```
echo "\"tom\" is a cat, and \"jerry\" is a mouse." | pee 'cut -d \" -f 2' 'cut -d \" -f 4'
```

or,

```
echo "\"tom\" is a cat, and \"jerry\" is a mouse." | pee 'cut -d \" -f 2' 'cut -d \" -f 4' | paste -d' ' - -
```