# Extracting strings from (BASIC) file

Tags: text-processing, scripting, macos

I am trying to extract all of the strings (in the order in which they appear), from a [BASIC listing for Taipan](https://github.com/greenonline/Taipan_40_Column_Apple_II/blob/main/TAIPAN_BAS_AppleII.txt). However, I also want the delimiting `"` (at the start and end of the strings) to also appear in the output as some of the strings have spaces at the end and I need to be able to "see" them and count them (and having the `"` at the end will ease that).

To further complicate matters, I am running on macOS so some of the grep arguments will differ from GNUgrep.

An example line (which contains two strings) is

```
1270 VTAB 19:PRINT " WE'VE CAPTURED A BIGGER SHIP!" : GOSUB 760:VTAB 19:PRINT " WE'RE TRANSFERRING TO IT NOW.": GOSUB 780:G = G + INT ( RND (1) * (G + 1)) + 1:E = SH + INT ( RND (1) * (SH + 150)) + 1: SH = SH + E:MW = MW + E:P=0
```

and the output that I require would be

```
...
" WE'VE CAPTURED A BIGGER SHIP!"
" WE'RE TRANSFERRING TO IT NOW."
...
```

I have managed to get just the lines containing `"` using<sup>1</sup>

```
grep -o '".*"'
```

but this is a greedy grep and I get two or more strings in one line, with non-string commands also being captured between the strings, rather than the individual strings from a multi-statement line being output on different lines, like so

```
" WE'VE CAPTURED A BIGGER SHIP!" : GOSUB 760:PRINT TAB(0,18) " WE'RE TRANSFERRING TO IT NOW."
```

Which is clearly not what I desire.

The following non-greedy `grep` doesn't seem to work correctly, and gives me less lines in the output (for some reason)<sup>2</sup>, probably because `grep` on macOS doesn't have the `-P` option.

```
grep -oP '".*?"'
```

Anyway, continuing with the output of `grep -o '".*"'`, if I pipe that into `awk` and look for the *even* fields<sup>3</sup>

```
grep -o '".*"' TAIPAN_BAS.txt | awk -F\" '{print $2}'
grep -o '".*"' TAIPAN_BAS.txt | awk -F\" '{print $4}'
grep -o '".*"' TAIPAN_BAS.txt | awk -F\" '{print $6}'
```

I will get more, or less, what I am after, except that the second (or third, or subsequent) strings on a multi-statement line are output *only after* all of the first occurrences of strings have been listed.

So, for example, using this as input

```
1270 VTAB 19:PRINT " WE'VE CAPTURED A BIGGER SHIP!" : GOSUB 760:VTAB 19:PRINT " WE'RE TRANSFERRING TO IT NOW.": GOSUB 780:G = G + INT ( RND (1) * (G + 1)) + 1:E = SH + INT ( RND (1) * (SH + 150)) + 1: SH = SH + E:MW = MW + E:P=0
1280 IF SR < .1 THEN 1300 
1281 IF P > 0 THEN 1050 
1285 REM ARRIVAL (1290)
1290 CR = 0: SR = 1:L=PO:V(L) = V(L) + 1: B=0:K=0:GOSUB 160:HOME:PRINT:INVERSE:PRINT A$;: NORMAL: PRINT " ARRIVING "; L$(L);" AFTER": PRINT " A VOYAGE OF ";ET;" DAYS.": INVERSE:PRINT A$:NORMAL: GOSUB 780: HOME:GOTO 120
```

will output the *n<sup>th</sup>* string(s) in "batches":

```
<first command output>
 WE'VE CAPTURED A BIGGER SHIP!
 ARRIVING 
<second command output>
 WE'RE TRANSFERRING TO IT NOW.
 AFTER
<third command output>
 A VOYAGE OF
```

whereas the output would be better, if ordered like this

```
 WE'VE CAPTURED A BIGGER SHIP!
 WE'RE TRANSFERRING TO IT NOW.
 ARRIVING 
 AFTER
 A VOYAGE OF
```

However, even with this "more desirable" output, there would be still two problems remaining:

- the final string (`" DAYS."`) is missing - I would need an *additional* command to get the eighth field, like so

  ```
  grep -o '".*"' TAIPAN_BAS.txt | awk -F\" '{print $8}'
  ```
- the double quotes are also missing.

This is what I would like to see (with: the double quotes; *all* of the strings, and; in the order of appearance):

```
" WE'VE CAPTURED A BIGGER SHIP!"
" WE'RE TRANSFERRING TO IT NOW."
" ARRIVING "
" AFTER"
" A VOYAGE OF "
" DAYS."
```

**Note**: None of the strings contain quotes (single or double) within them - apart from the apostrophes.

##### My questions are:

- How can I look for *all* of the even fields on a multi-statement line, without having to issue a *separate* command for *each* field - isn't there a programmatical way to express `{print $2 $4 $6 ...}`, etc., in `awk`?
- How can I splice the second and third occurrences in to the file, so that they appear in order, rather than in batches of occurences (all first string occurrences, all second string occurrence, third string occurrence, etc.)

  - I have tried this

    ```
    grep -o '".*"' TAIPAN_BAS.txt | awk -F\" '{printf $2,"\\n"$4"\\n"$6}'
    ```

    But every thing was output on one line, only the first string instances were output, and the newlines (`\\n`) seem to be ignored.
- How can I stop `awk` from removing the field separator (i.e. `"`)?

Again I am on macOS, so GNU solutions might not help. Also, I'm open to using `sed` or something else (I've already tried `cut` and `tr` on their own but they just removed the `"` and left loads of code).

---

<sup>1</sup> From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553516/97255) to [How do I extract the content of quoted strings from the output of a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137030/97255)

<sup>2</sup> After re-checking, it just gives me the "usage" message.

<sup>3</sup> From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210375/97255) to [extract string between double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/210370/97255).

Comment: Did you try the simple BRE `grep -o '"[^"]*"'` ?

Comment: Ah yeah, that's it. So simple! Looking through my history, I *had* tried it earlier, but I had used the wrong arguments (i.e. `grep -oP '"[^"]*"'`) and the mac barfed at the `-P`, so I assumed it was wrong. Many thanks :-D

Comment: A different approach is to convert all double quotes to newlines and all newlines to double quotes. Then take every other line,and put a double quote at the start and end of it. You can use `tr \"\n \n\" < infile | awk 'NR%2 ==0' {printf("\"%s\"\n", $0) }' `which should not have any gnu dependencies in it.

Comment: @icarus -  that gives me a pipe quote prompt

Comment: My normal approach would be to just use `awk -F\" '{for(i=2;i<NF;i+=2) {printf("\"%s\"\n", $i)}' infile` to print the "even"' fields.

Comment: Oops, shouldn't have a single quote after the ==0. Sorry

Comment: @icarus -  ah, a `for` loop, ok. Thanks.

Comment: @icarus. Ok, removed the `'` but it just gives me the listing with added quotes around each line.

Comment: I do wonder, what do you get with `grep -oP '".*?"'` on the Mac? If (when) the `-P` option isn't supported, it probably should just give you an error message...

Comment: @icarus, you need `\"\\n`, or `'"\n'` and so on. `tr \"\n \n\"` would change doublequotes to letters n...

Comment: How are `"`s inside quoted strings represented - `"this ""is"" quoted"` or `"this \"is\" quoted"` or something else? Please include an example of that in your sample input/output. Can newlines appear inside the quoted strings?

Comment: Note that `-o` and `-P` are both non-standard extensions for `grep` so don't rely on either of them for a portable solution if you care about that.

Comment: @ilkkachu - It just gives me the usage, i.e. `usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne '.put for .comb( / \" <-["]>+? \" /);'  file
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -ne '.put for .comb( / \" ~ \" <-["]>+?  /);'  file
```

Here are answers coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Raku features a powerful Regex/Grammar engine that can be used to parse code (See: ["A simple parser in Raku grammars"](https://andrewshitov.com/2018/10/31/a-simple-parser-in-perl-6-grammars/)).

Above you can `comb` the code to search for patterns you desire. To create a custom character class looking for quotation mark use `<+["]>` for positive selection and `<-["]>` for negative selection. The second answer uses Raku's `~` tilde notation, which is useful for extracting nested text elements and/or their surrounds.

Sample Input:

```
1270 VTAB 19:PRINT " WE'VE CAPTURED A BIGGER SHIP!" : GOSUB 760:VTAB 19:PRINT " WE'RE TRANSFERRING TO IT NOW.": GOSUB 780:G = G + INT ( RND (1) * (G + 1)) + 1:E = SH + INT ( RND (1) * (SH + 150)) + 1: SH = SH + E:MW = MW + E:P=0
1280 IF SR < .1 THEN 1300 
1281 IF P > 0 THEN 1050 
1285 REM ARRIVAL (1290)
1290 CR = 0: SR = 1:L=PO:V(L) = V(L) + 1: B=0:K=0:GOSUB 160:HOME:PRINT:INVERSE:PRINT A$;: NORMAL: PRINT " ARRIVING "; L$(L);" AFTER": PRINT " A VOYAGE OF ";ET;" DAYS.": INVERSE:PRINT A$:NORMAL: GOSUB 780: HOME:GOTO 120

1295 REM THAT'S ALL FOLKS (1300-1321)
1300 HOME:NW = C - D:Q = NW / GT: VTAB 4: INVERSE: PRINT A$;: NORMAL: PRINT:PRINT "YOUR SCORE, BASED UPON TIME AND YOUR": PRINT "NET WORTH (EXCLUDING STOCK) IS ";: GOSUB 1330:INVERSE: PRINT A$: NORMAL
1310 IF X$ = "R" THEN PRINT "WOULD YOU LIKE TO PICK UP THIS":PRINT"GAME WHERE YOU LEFT OFF (Y/N)?": GOSUB 60:IF X$ = "Y" THEN HOME:GOTO 120
1320 GOSUB 1340: VTAB 10:PRINT A$;: PRINT "DO YOU WISH TO START OVER (Y/N)?": GOSUB 60:IF X$ = "Y" THEN RUN
1321 END
```

Sample Output:

```
" WE'VE CAPTURED A BIGGER SHIP!"
" WE'RE TRANSFERRING TO IT NOW."
" ARRIVING "
" AFTER"
" A VOYAGE OF "
" DAYS."
"YOUR SCORE, BASED UPON TIME AND YOUR"
"NET WORTH (EXCLUDING STOCK) IS "
"R"
"WOULD YOU LIKE TO PICK UP THIS"
"GAME WHERE YOU LEFT OFF (Y/N)?"
"Y"
"DO YOU WISH TO START OVER (Y/N)?"
"Y"
```

The above Sample Output is just to get you started. You can also record the line-number that the quoted string is found on:

```
~$ raku -e ' for lines.kv -> $k,$v { put "$k\t$_" for $v.comb( / \" <-["]>+? \" /)};' file
0   " WE'VE CAPTURED A BIGGER SHIP!"
0   " WE'RE TRANSFERRING TO IT NOW."
4   " ARRIVING "
4   " AFTER"
4   " A VOYAGE OF "
4   " DAYS."
7   "YOUR SCORE, BASED UPON TIME AND YOUR"
7   "NET WORTH (EXCLUDING STOCK) IS "
8   "R"
8   "WOULD YOU LIKE TO PICK UP THIS"
8   "GAME WHERE YOU LEFT OFF (Y/N)?"
8   "Y"
9   "DO YOU WISH TO START OVER (Y/N)?"
9   "Y"
```

Finally, Raku's `grep` can really help you if you want to return the "Program Line Number" as it filters out error-causing blank lines:

```
~$ raku -e 'for lines.grep(*.chars).map( *.split(" ", 2)) { my $k = .[0];  my $v = .[1];  put "$k\t$_" for $v.comb( / \" <-["]>+? \" /) };'  file
1270    " WE'VE CAPTURED A BIGGER SHIP!"
1270    " WE'RE TRANSFERRING TO IT NOW."
1290    " ARRIVING "
1290    " AFTER"
1290    " A VOYAGE OF "
1290    " DAYS."
1300    "YOUR SCORE, BASED UPON TIME AND YOUR"
1300    "NET WORTH (EXCLUDING STOCK) IS "
1310    "R"
1310    "WOULD YOU LIKE TO PICK UP THIS"
1310    "GAME WHERE YOU LEFT OFF (Y/N)?"
1310    "Y"
1320    "DO YOU WISH TO START OVER (Y/N)?"
1320    "Y"
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Tilde_for_nesting_structures
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org

Comment: Having the line number in the text file is actually quite useful. I might try playing with this to get it to display the BASIC line number (instead, or as well) .

Comment: @Greenonline Updated!

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted your answer as you seem to have gone the extra mile (w.r.t. the line numbers - that weren't part of the initial question). It was a difficult decision as Ed's answer addresses the `awk` aspect of my question, and ilkkachu's answer actually gives me the simple `grep` that I had initially been after. It just goes to show that my rambling question wasn't well thought out and was too broad (i.e. asked too many questions in one post). I should have split it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

The `-P` option stands for Perl, and uses Perl regexes, so where it's not available, you could just use Perl directly...

```
% perl -lne 'print $& while /".*?"/g' file2.txt
" WE'VE CAPTURED A BIGGER SHIP!"
" WE'RE TRANSFERRING TO IT NOW."
" ARRIVING "
" AFTER"
" A VOYAGE OF "
" DAYS."
```

(`$&` is the
matched string in full, and you know already what `".*?"` is.)

But of course, since the end marker is just a single character, you can just match anything that's not a double-quote between the two required double-quotes, even in regular `grep`:

```
% grep -oe  '"[^"]*"' file2.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -F'"' '{for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) print FS $i FS}' file
" WE'VE CAPTURED A BIGGER SHIP!"
" WE'RE TRANSFERRING TO IT NOW."
" ARRIVING "
" AFTER"
" A VOYAGE OF "
" DAYS."
```

The above assumes you do not have `"`s or newlines inside your quoted strings.

If you can then the right solution will depend on how `"`s inside `"`-delimited strings are represented (not allowed or escaped by doubling `""` or escaped by backslash `\"` or something else) and how newlines should be handled (printed as-is, converted to blanks, or something else).

Comment: The assumption that there are no quotes within the strings, nor newline (nor return) characters is correct (at least, in this case). Thanks for the awk version, that makes sense.